# Can I take my Macbook Pro 2015 on my Aegean/Lufthansa flight?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, regulations, electronic-items, lufthansa

Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) [banned](https://www.businessinsider.de/macbook-pro-banned-airlines-list-2019-8?r=US&IR=T) these kind of laptops. However, I will fly from Munich to London, and at a later date from Munich to Athens. FAA is a USA organisation though, which makes me wonder:

Is the Macbook Pro 2015 laptop allowed in flights across the European Union?

Comment: **Apple has a recall out on this model's battery**.  That means Apple will fix it for free, and it also means you should really, really let them fix it.  Otherwise you're walking around with a bomb.  Forget the airplane, it could burn down your house! Just get it fixed...

Comment: @Harper, will replacing the battery change whether he can take the laptop on a plane?

Comment: @Harper At least I hope this ticking time bomb was affordable!

Comment: @Haeper thanks for the information! Downvoter: if you think my question can be improved, please let me know. An friend of mine got into trouble with his Mac when flying with Transavia, so I thought it would be a good idea to ask... As the answers suggest too!

Comment: @gsamaras Can you clarify how your friend got into trouble? How did they know his laptop was under a recall (they're visually indistinguishable from older models)? What did they demand from him? What happened in the end?

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky All a traveler can do is carry the receipt from the work, or, perhaps, a scan of the receipt document on a phone. I haven't heard of the public distribution of a "repaired" database, and given the volume of travelers who carry laptops, reference to a database, even if available, is unlikely to be practical.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky, I wasn't completely honest. He is just a guy I barely know from the uni-he posted on social, I asked him for further details, and that was his single worded answer, so I don't want to ask for more. His post sparked my decision to ask an answer here, which I hope it will help others, as it helped me too!

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Macbook models are not indistinguishable, they just don't change their style every year.  There are numbers on the back of the machine (and battery, if separable) which indicate things like its model, serial number and the like.

Comment: @Harper I checked in Apple's [site](https://support.apple.com/15-inch-macbook-pro-battery-recall), and got "It's not in the affected serial number range.". Wonder how to communicate this to the airport/airline staff? Make a screenshot? If you think this comment should be transformed into a post, please let me know. Thanks again for informing me. :) You are amongst the plethora of the beings that make StackExchange a helpful place! :D

Comment: @gsamaras yes, I believe that is a fine answer.  Both screenshot and printout, for those who still think on paper.

Comment: @gsamaras Have you flown with the MacBook in the meantime? Did you encounter any extra checks? If so, how did you handle it? Was a printout stating the battery was not affected/replaced sufficient? If you know more about the actual process, I would be grateful if you could make another answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I flew in 2019, but I don't recall any extra checks/questions other than the typical ones for any laptop when pass through security. I suggest you contact the airport and your airliner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lufthansa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/147312/i-cannot-take-my-macbook-pro-2015-in-my-aegean-lufthansa-flight) has made a statement about this:

> ## Information on the carriage of Apple MacBooks
>
> Apple has recalled certain 15 inch models of Macbook Pro laptops sold between 2015 and 2017 as a result of a battery defect. If the battery of those specific recalled models were not replaced by the manufacturer, the passenger will not be able to carry the laptop on board the aircraft. Lufthansa is following a safety directive from the European Aviation Safety Authority (EASA) which has been in force since February 2017. It prohibits the transportation of defective lithium batteries or those affected by a recall. Lufthansa crews are carefully trained in handling lithium batteries.

Aegean has published no statement on this, so as mentioned in the [other answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147314/89966), presumably this is allowed.

Comment: It's called Aegean, from the sea between Minor Asia and Mainland of Greece, named after Aegeus, the father of Theseus, who jumped into the sea from Sounion, when he saw the Black sails on his son's ship, who had gone to kill Minotaur. Theseus had indeed succeeded in that, but ecstasied from happiness, forgot to change his sails from black to white - and thus his father thought he was killed, just like all the rest who fought against Minotaur. (That myth as a thank you gesture for your answer).

Comment: Any information on how to prove (or if/what proof is needed) that the battery has been exchanged?

Comment: @MarkJohnson Looks like it'd be OK on the Lufthansa segment as shown in Daniil's answer. Carrying a physical receipt for the work (or a scan on one's phone) is the only thing I can imagine being done by the passenger.